# Removing Extra Space Around QTabWidget in a QMainWindow Layout in PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2, qmainwindow, qtabwidget, qlayout

I'm working with a PySide2 application and encountering an issue where there's unexpected extra space around my `QTabWidget` within a `QMainWindow` after moving tabs to the `QMenuBar`. This is in a context of a `QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint` QMainWindow.

I've tried setting the content margins of the every widgets / layouts to 0, but it doesn't seem to remove the extra space (in green on the screenshot).

Here's how the UI is structured:

- **Green**: QMainWindow
- **Yellow**: QTabWidget
- **Red**: QTabBar
- **Blue**: QMenuBar

[image]

Here's a minimal code snippet where I move tabs to the QMenuBar:

```py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tab_widget = TabWidget()
    
    def toggle_frameless(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.menuBar().setLayout(layout)
        self.menuBar().layout().addWidget(self.tab_widget.tab_bar)
        self.menuBar().layout().addStretch()
```

I suspect that the QTabWidget keep the geometry of the tabs, but I can't find a way to remove this extra space.
I'm attaching a screenshot to show the issue visually with colors on backgrounds:
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You cannot detach and reparent inner widgets, like the QTabBar of a QTabWidget. Just use a standalone QTabBar and a QStackedWidget to display the pages each tab represents (which is exactly what QTabWidget internally does).

Comment: ok thanks, that what I thought. Was looking for a way to touch as little as possible to the existing codebase. Will check with team for a bigger refactor then. Thanks for your time

Comment: Well, if you want to easily switch between those modes, you could use a work around: hide the tab bar and create a copy of it, including its existing tabs, and connect the QTabBar signals to the QTabWidget slots. Obviously, if you added some extended aspects, like closable tabs, drag&drop, etc, you have to consider that too. Also note that you should not try to set a layout to QMenuBar, because it has its own layout management for items, which doesn't take into account any "extra" layout you may have attempted to set. I don't know how you achieved the result above, but it's unreliable.

Comment: In the case of menubar, you *could* try what you attempted with QTabBar, and add the current menubar to the title bar layout, but I'm not completely sure about the consequences. In theory, it should work: the private layout of QMainWindow is still a QLayout, so it supports `QLayout.setMenuBar()` (which you can call if you want to toggle back to normal window appearance, and it's actually what `QMainWindow.setMenuBar()` does, among other things); but, again, you cannot be 100% sure, as it's possible that some QStyles will not check the layout and assume the menubar is still at its place.

Comment: Hey!
Thanks for all the solutions. In the end, my team agreed that I should take the time to do a refactor, so we'll recreate the bar from 0, with a QWidget, QTabBar, a QStackedWidget etc... it will indeed be much cleaner than doing little hacks all over the place.

Comment: for this part: "[...] I don't know how you got the above result, but it's not reliable", if we put a layout in the QMenuBar, self.menuBar().setLayout(QHBoxLayout()) This just stacks what we put in that layout under the one handled by the menuBar(). As in our case, there's nothing in it, so it makes the coffee, even if it's horrible.

thank you for the time you've taken to reply, and have a good evening.